# JS Progressive Web App: how to fire an event on "visibilitychange" event before the app preview is created?

Tags: javascript, css, events, frontend, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to blur the PWA app preview when the user switches between the apps on a phone.
Here's my attempt:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange);

function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (document.visibilityState === "hidden") {
    blurScreen();
  } else {
    unblurScreen();
  }
}

function blurScreen() {
  // Apply blur effect to the app's content
  document.body.style.filter = "blur(5px)";
}

function unblurScreen() {
  // Remove blur effect from the app's content
  document.body.style.filter = "none";
}
```

The problem is that the filter applies after the preview image was generated.
Is there a way to solve this? Thanks